# How to Fixed / Lock Position of Background Image & Divs Containing Images

Tags: html, css, image, position

I have a map image (1080x1080px) I want this to be the the background of the body or a container div. I need the image to stay fixed in its place always, even when resizing the browser window.

I have divs inside of the main div container and these divs have images which are map markers that have been places at specific locations and they are toggled on and off as required.

Both the background image (map) and the markers need to stay in their position permanently.

How can I achieve this? What I have is not working...

```css
body, html {
  height: 100%;
}

#bg {
  background-image: url(treasuremap_01.jpg);
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 1080px 1080px;
  position: relative;
  }

  #menu {
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
  }

  input:checked + .hidable {
    display: none;
  }
  
  input:not(:checked) + .showable {
    display: none;
  }

  #mark01 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 240px;
    right: 490px;
  }

  #mark02 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 480px;
    left: 460px;
  }

  #mark03 {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 260px;
    right: 490px;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
<title>Treasure Map</title>
</head>
<body>

  <div id="bg">
    <div id="menu">
      <input type="checkbox" /> Marker 1
      <div class="showable"><img id="mark01" src="xmark_01.png" alt="X Mark Red"></div>
      <input type="checkbox" /> Marker 2
      <div class="showable"><img id="mark02" src="xmark_02.png" alt="X Mark Green"></div>
      <input type="checkbox" /> Marker 3
      <div class="showable"><img id="mark03" src="xmark_03.png" alt="X Mark Magenta"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `#bg` property of `width` and `height` the same as the `background-image` size.

```css
body, html {
  height: 100%;
}

#bg {
  background-image: url(http://basicblue.biz/treasure/treasuremap_01.jpg);
  height: 1080px;
  width: 1080px;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 1080px 1080px;
  position: relative;
  }

  #menu {
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
  }

  input:checked + .hidable {
    display: none;
  }
  
  input:not(:checked) + .showable {
    display: none;
  }

  #mark01 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 240px;
    right: 490px;
  }

  #mark02 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 480px;
    left: 460px;
  }

  #mark03 {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 260px;
    right: 490px;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
<title>Treasure Map</title>
</head>
<body>

  <div id="bg">
    <div id="menu">
      <input type="checkbox" /> Marker 1
      <div class="showable"><img id="mark01" src="http://basicblue.biz/treasure/xmark_01.png" alt="X Mark Red"></div>
      <input type="checkbox" /> Marker 2
      <div class="showable"><img id="mark02" src="http://basicblue.biz/treasure/xmark_02.png" alt="X Mark Green"></div>
      <input type="checkbox" /> Marker 3
      <div class="showable"><img id="mark03" src="http://basicblue.biz/treasure/xmark_03.png" alt="X Mark Magenta"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ok thanks silly me. I have updated the code. This is a partial solution as it locks the background image in place perfectly but the markers do stay in their place if the browser resizes,

Comment: This works and thanks for a quick reply with a simple fix. I am still learning ;)

Answer (score 0):

I'm only loading the background image in the HTML in the case that you're pulling the image dynamically via PHP. Otherwise, you can create separate classes with background images in the CSS file.

fixed and cover didn't use to play well together, and you would have to put the height property in an outer container, but I tested this code on Chrome, Firefox, Safari, and Opera, and it works fine.

Comment: Thanks as it is not working for me. I want the actual map (background) to stay in place instead of moving when the browser resizes. More importantly I want the markers (divs with images) to stay fixed in their places on the map. Ideally all components will stay fixed in place or alternatively, they must resize together. Can this even be done? Hope this makes sense... ;)

Answer (score 0):

div {
  width: 100%
  height: 90vh
  background-repeat: no-repeat
  background-position: center center
  background-size: cover
  background-attachment: fixed
} . End every of the sentence in an hyfin

Answer (score 0):

Thanks but it won't send I'm trying to find a way out to send in a simple language programming. You can also write this code in the background shorthand then you'd simply add the background image to the div and adjust the height property as necessary.

Apostrophe in between the backgroundimage and and hyfin to end it to get the picture

Comment: i did not see this

Comment: I can't send either maybe PC will do